# Unable to test PHP methods in postman

Tags: php, rest, postman

I have tested many REST APIs in postman but never came across such API which contains `$_REQUEST['method']` which decide what method is to call. now my question is how can I test this APIs on postman. How do I pass `$_REQUEST['method']` name in postman.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php 
include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_REQUEST['method'])){
// echo '<pre>';

    if($_POST['method']=='create'){

        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        // $images = null;
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $specility = $_POST['specility'];
        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".time().'-'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $path_name="images/".$file;

        move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$path_name);


        $query = "INSERT into `restaurant` (name, location, image, rating,specility) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$path_name', '$rating','$specility')";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        if($result){
            echo json_encode(['status'=>'success','response'=>'Restaurant created successfuly']);       
        }else{
            echo json_encode(['status'=>'failed','response'=>'Restaurant details are not proper']);     
        }

    }

    if($_POST['method']=='list'){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `restaurant`";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  
            echo json_encode(['status'=>'success','response'=>$data]);      
        }else{
            echo json_encode(['status'=>'failed','response'=>'No data found']);     
        }

    }

}else{
    echo json_encode(['status'=>'failed','response'=>'Something went wrong']);
}
```

I also hosted this APIs on server. I don't know what I search on internet to solve this issue. see my image below, for security reasons I have changed url.

[image]

Please tell me how do I do it.

Comment: Can you show your request parameters ?

Comment: which parameters?

Comment: Request parameter

Comment: Add the key "method" with the value "create" or "list" as required in your script.

Comment: should I add that in `form-data` under body section

Comment: Yes It got solved. Thanks @ARN

Answer (score 0):

You can pass method key in post variables. $_REQUEST can accept any request type whether it is post type of get type. So you just need to pass method key either in get or post. And if you want to check whether request was post or get, you can check that as below:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
}
```

Hope it helps you.